# neo4j 2.0 not creating node but running successfully

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, node-neo4j

Have a Neo4j 2.0 enterprise instance running.  Using the jars from the lib directory to run this groovy script

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService
import org.neo4j.graphdb.ResourceIterable
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory
import org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase
import org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node

String DB_PATH = "/Users/afrieden/Neo4j/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0-M03/"
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH)

Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()
try {
   Node runNode = graphDb.createNode()
   println("we made it!")
   tx.success()
}
finally{
  tx.finish()
}
graphDb.shutdown()
```

Runs successfully with the output of "we made it".  However when I go into my webadmin cypher console and run

```
START n=node(*) RETURN n;
```

I get only the starting node with nothing in it.  Is there a log anywhere where I can find what it is choking on?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Web Admin is pointing to the same place as the `DB_PATH` in your code. You can find the Web Admin properties in `conf/neo4j-server.properties` of your neo4j directory

Answer (score 0):

Turns out they weren't pointing to the same place.  Also in 2.0 if you are running embedded mode in two different places it won't fuss at you, however it will not update the database.  I had the webadmin running and the script running on top of it.

Comment: What do you mean 2 different places? You mean the embedded pointing somewhere other than where the web admin points? That's the point of Neo4j is that it's not tied to any one location, but you can point any embedded at a directory and it will work there.

Comment: I mean that two places were trying to use the embedded database and it wasn't throwing an error when the second one tried to access it.

Comment: Oh. If correct, that should be raised as a bug I believe, as Neo4j, at least as of version 1.9, locks to files and nothing else should be allowed to acquire them, and Neo4j should throw an error. If you can, you should open a bug report on their GitHub account.

Comment: It seems to lock it (doesn't update the data) but in 1.9 it would throw an error saying you can't access those files.

Comment: Exactly. This may be a bug in the current 2.0 Milestone, which is why I believe it would be best to open a ticket with them.

Comment: in neo4j 2.0 I think we have to specify db location in two property files

neo4j.properties

&

neo4j-server.properties

actualy db location is listed in server properties not in ne04j.properties !!!